# Attach a default color palette to my account?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a bunch of specific colors that I use for my gSheets & gDocs, but every time I open a new file, I have to start over again and apply my colors.

How can I set it up so that Sheets/Docs default colors match the ones I want?